# Proteoglycans vs Glycoproteins

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane, histology, glucose, carbohydrates

[image]

On the left, is my histology book, on the right there's qoura (the internet). 
My histology textbook says that "unlike glycoproteins, proteoglycans have attached GAGs which often **comprise a greater mass** than the polypeptide core"

What I found on qoura is "The carbohydrate content of proteoglycans (10-15%) is far less than glycoproteins is (50-60%)"

I tried googling the question but couldn't find the answer so which of these is correct ?

Comment: Campbell Biology (11th edition) states that proteoglycans are up to 95% carbohydrate.

Answer (score 2):

More context would be helpful, but it's possible the data from the Quora post was incorrectly transcribed from a table on [this biotech site](https://astartebio.com/blog/ask-scientist-proteoglycans-vs-glycoproteins/), which states that the carbohydrate content of proteoglycans is 50-60%, compared to 10-15% for glycoproteins.

[image]

However, the first comment on that page suggests that the table was initially incorrect:

> Hi Anne,
>
> This is a great post, but the numbers for the carbohydrate content are reversed. It’s 50-60% for the proteoglycans and 10-15% for most common glycoproteins (and things like uromodulin and most mucins would be 30+% sugars).
>
> Best,
>
> Jared Gerlach

So that may be the source of confusion, here.  It seems the commenter is an [expert in the field of glycan research](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=3iLuV0wAAAAJ&hl=en), so the table is likely correct.

Comment: Was the table edited afterwards ? Because the table shows 50-60% carbs in proteoglycans and 10-15% in glycoproteins which the writer and the commenter agree on

Comment: Yes, it seems that is the case.  I've edited my answer to reflect that, thanks.